# Can I prove an euclidean geometry problems by linear transformation?

Tags: group-theory

I read some article, and It says
"the definition of linear tranformation is a function of $\mathcal{R}^N$→$\mathcal{R}^N$
so, among linear transformations, non 0 determinant Invertible Linear Transformations construct a group, and these functions on vector space $\mathcal{R}^N$.
among these linear transformation, If we only treat rigid motion, this can be thought of as an euclidean geometry"
I know nothing about algebra, but then can I solve a traditional euclidean geometry problems and get meaningful results by linear transformation? or is it just nothing more than proving the known facts again?

Comment: There’s more to being a linear transformation than simply being a function from $\mathbb R^N$ to $\mathbb R^N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can derive the area of an ellipse using matrices. If you know that the area of the unit circle is $\pi$, and recall that the absolute value of the determinant tells you how you are scaling area, then taking the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}
$$
and noticing that it extends the diameter of the unit circle along the $x$ axis by $a$ and the diameter along the $y$ axis by $b$, creating an ellipse, you can figure out that the area of this ellipse is 
$$
\pi \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}\right)=\pi ab
$$